# Gulp4, gulp-imacss and Deprecation Warning

Tags: gulp, deprecation-warning

I study work with Gulp 4 and use plugin 'gulp-imacss' and other

```
var imacss = require('gulp-imacss')
```

farther

```
var imguri = {
        in: source + 'images/inline/*',
        out: source + 'scss/images/',
        filename: '_datauri.scss',
        namespace: 'img'
    }
```

create task that convert images to dataURIs in SCSS source

```
gulp.task('imguri', function () {
    return gulp.src(imguri.in)
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(imacss(imguri.filename, imguri.namespace))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(imguri.out))
});
```

Run `gulp imguri` in terminal and get:

> Starting 'imguri'...
>
> (node:90037) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in
>   MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of
>   MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead.
>
> The following tasks did not complete: imguri
>
> Did you forget to signal async completion?

I don't understand what to do with the code because of this Deprecation Warning.